# Vertx JWKS/JWT verification throws a 500 with no errors logged

Tags: jwt, vert.x

I have a very basic Vertx demo I'm trying to create that fetches a JWK from an endpoint and creates an RSAPublicKey for verifying a JWT signature:

```
package example;

import com.auth0.jwk.JwkException;
import com.auth0.jwk.JwkProvider;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.RSAKeyProvider;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;


public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.route().handler(routingContext -> {
      String authHeader = routingContext.request().getHeader("Authorization");
      // pull token from header
      String token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
      URL jwksEndpoint = null;
      try {
        jwksEndpoint = new URL("http://localhost:1080/jwks");
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      JwkProvider jwkProvider = new UrlJwkProvider(jwksEndpoint);

      RSAKeyProvider keyProvider = new RSAKeyProvider() {
        @Override
        public RSAPublicKey getPublicKeyById(String kid) {
          //Received 'kid' value might be null if it wasn't defined in the Token's header
          RSAPublicKey publicKey = null;
          try {
            publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) jwkProvider.get(kid).getPublicKey();
          } catch (JwkException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return publicKey;
        }

        @Override
        public RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrivateKeyId() {
          return null;
        }
      };

      Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(keyProvider);
      JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
        .withIssuer("auth0")
        .build();
      DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
      System.out.println(jwt);

      routingContext.next();
    });

    router.route("/hello").handler(ctx -> {
      ctx.response()
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
        .end("<h1>Hello from non-clustered messenger example!</h1>");
    });

    server.requestHandler(router).listen(8888, http -> {
      if(http.succeeded()) {
        startPromise.complete();
        System.out.println("HTTP server started on port 8888");
      } else {
        startPromise.fail(http.cause());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I make request to the /hello endpoint, the application immediately returns a 500. But nothing appears in the logs (even at debug level).

I've tried manually specifying the `kid` property to rule out the jwkProvider not returning properly

I'm at a loss at how to gain any more insight into what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to completely be my oversight. Wrapping that `verifier.verify()` call in a `try/catch` showed me that I was expecting an issuer. This is the same problem I was having while trying to achieve this in Quarkus! I was able to remove that from the builder and now this works perfectly.